# @SessionAttribute confusing

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Controller class which have the login functionality. It have two method : getCustomer to get customer info from database to keep in session, submitLoginForm to check if customer (or user) log in success (login fail if getCustomer return null and run to error page). But one thing keep me confusing is the when I input true username and password

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("customer")
public class LoginController {
    
    @Autowired
    CustomerService customService;
    
    // get username and password to log in
    @ModelAttribute("customer")
    public Customer getCustomer(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password) {

            Customer c = customService.getCustomer(username, password);
            return c;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/login")
    public String submitLoginForm(@SessionAttribute(required=false) Customer customer, Model model) {
        
        if(customer != null) {
            // login successfully
            return "redirect:/";
        } else {
            // login unsuccessfully
            model.addAttribute("message","wrong username or password");
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

When I login with true username and password, I get the error page instead of the home page. But when I type the homepage url the homepage show up with the username I have logged in successfully

Here is my login form

```
<form action="login" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="username" required/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="password" required/>
                            
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: show your form! (sounds like always `customer==null` (in post mapping)?)

Comment: ..and what is `@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password`, when the page is loaded for the *first time*? (without query/params!?) ;);)

Comment: @xerx593 I have added my login form on my question

Comment: @xerx593 No it seems like the customer in the argument have null value initially(which led to error page and login failed). But when I run to the homepage by typing url, the customer not null anymore (login suddenly success)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it so (untested):

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("customer")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerService customService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/login")
    public String submitLoginForm(
      @RequestParam String username, 
      @RequestParam String password,
      Model model
    ) {
        Customer customer = customService.getCustomer(username, password);
        if(customer != null) {
            // login successfully
            model.addAtribute("customer", customer); // !!
            return "redirect:/";
        } else {
            // login unsuccessfully
            model.addAttribute("message","wrong username or password");
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

- Don't "expose" any `@ModelAttribute`, since our form("view"!) does not need/use it. (as much can see)
- But instead:

  - send `@RequestParam`s to `submitLoginForm()` (according with the html form)
  - add a model/session attribute on successful login (i.e. on form submission).

After this (`model.addAttribute`), we can access `"customer"` (model/session) attribute from any view/controller within this session (due/thx to SessionAttributes annotation).

---

For this to work:

```
@ModelAttribute("customer")
public Customer getCustomer(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password) {
    Customer c = customService.getCustomer(username, password);
    return c;
}
```

We'd already have to call(GET) it like: `/login?username=admin&password=se3cret` (surpassing the `submitLoginForm()`..).

Comment: so when I call this controller, it will run the submitLoginForm method first and getCustomer second right ? I thought it was vice versa

Comment: sorry, which this? to make your (OP) controller work (it works!): we need to `GET /login?username=admin&password=se3cret`  (with correct credentials) (..after that it is irrelevant, what we type into the form!!!!)

Comment: with my proposed(answer) controller: we `GET /login` (no query), and then have to type the correct credentials into form & hit submit... ;) (the GET mapping is assumed simple... return "login" (or so ..if ANY!:):).)